# Не работает метод в другом классе

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь вызвать метод в классе SpawnBehavior, не работает.
Работает только во втором классе PropSpawn. Подскажите решение или в чем проблема!

Суть механики заключается в том что, при нажатии на кнопку GameObject переносится на точку локации.

Первый класс: Отвечает за запись точек локации в List

```
public class SpawnLocations : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static SpawnLocations Api { get; set; }

    public void Awake()
    {
        Api = this;
        TakeSpawnLocations();
      
    }


    public Transform spawnLocations;
    public List<Transform> locations;



    public void TakeSpawnLocations()
    {

        foreach (Transform child in spawnLocations)
        {

            locations.Add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Второй класс: Отвечает за то, что когда вызывается метод, Item1(GameObject) переносится к точке локации Location1(GameObject)

```
public class PropSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PropSpawn Api { get; set; }

    public Transform _transformLocations = SpawnLocations.Api.locations[0];

    public PropSpawn(Transform transformLocations)
    {
        _transformLocations = transformLocations;
    }

    public Transform _propTransformLocation = SpawnItemsLocations.Api.locations[0];

    public Transform TransformLocations { get { return _transformLocations; } set { _transformLocations = value; } }
    public Transform PropTransformLocations { get { return _propTransformLocation; } set { _propTransformLocation = value; } }


    public void Spawn() 
    {  
        _propTransformLocation.position = new Vector3(_transformLocations.position.x, _transformLocations.position.y, _transformLocations.position.z);  
    }
}
```

Третий класс: Главный менеджер игры, вызываю метод в public void OnGUI(), после того как нажмется кнопка. Не вызывается и не переносит Item1 к Location1

А возникает ошибка.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object SpawnBehaviour.OnGUI () (at Assets/MergePrototype/Scripts/SpawnBehaviour.cs:19)

```
public class SpawnBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void OnGUI()
    {
       if  (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 20, 150, 25), "Tap the spawn!"))
        {

            PropSpawn.Api.Spawn();

        }
      
    }

}
```

GameObject находятся в иерархии.

SpawnLoc:

- Location1

PropSpawnCollection:

- Item1

Comment: И ещё, пожалуйста, поясните, в чём заключается "не работает". Приведите текст возникающей ошибки.

Comment: Пару минут, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @mymedia исправил

Comment: Да, спасибо. Скажите, какую-то ошибку компилятор выдаёт? Так я вижу, второй класс не является родительским для двух остальных.

Comment: @mymedia, извиняюсь, вот увидел ошибку NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SpawnBehaviour.OnGUI () (at Assets/MergePrototype/Scripts/SpawnBehaviour.cs:19)

Comment: Ошибка появляется после того как пытаюсь вызвать метод через кнопку

Comment: @mymedia решил проблему. Забыл во второй класс после Api добавить public void Awake()
    {
        Api = this;
    }
Ссылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во втором классе после `Api` забыли добавить:

```
public void Awake(){Api = this;}
```